# Itens não são mostrados no dataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Estou usando o seguinte código para incluir itens em uma lista e mostrar a mesma no meu `DataGridView`:

```
PedidodetalheOffline item = new PedidodetalheOffline(); //crio um novo item
item.IdOffline = id; //seto o id
item.PedidoOffline = numero; //seto o numero do pedido
item.ItemOffline = iditem; //seto o item
pedido.Add(item); //adiciono o item à lista "pedido"
id++; //incremento a variavel id para nao repetir

MessageBox.Show(pedido.Count().ToString()); //quantidade de intens que tem na lista
gridPedido.DataSource = pedido; //passo a lista pro DataGridView
```

Esse é o código do botão que inclui itens na lista e passa pro `DataGridView`. O que ocorre é que na primeira vez funciona (o primeiro item é mostrado dentro do `DataGridView`), mas à partir do segundo, não funciona (continua mostrando apenas o primeiro). Incluí a `MessageBox` pra confirmar que os itens estão sendo incluídos na lista e confirmei que estão sim.

*O que pode ser? Será que tem algum comando pra atualizar a lista ou o `DataGridView` cada vez que incluo um novo item?*

Comment: `pedido` é o que?

Comment: pedido é a lista

Comment: escreve assim `gridPedido.DataSource = pedido.ToList()`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado. Se quiser, posta a resposta pra eu marcar. Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Troque isso:*

```
gridPedido.DataSource = pedido;
```

*por isso:*

```
gridPedido.DataSource = pedido.ToList();
```

forçando o tipo de dado enviado para `DataSource` do `DataGridView` `List<T>`. Esse `DataSource` pode receber os tipos implementados das interfaces:

- `IList` e `IList<T>`,
- `IListSource` (Exemplo: `DataTable` e `DataSet`),
- `IBindingList` (Exemplo: `BindingList<T>` classe) e
- `IBindingListView`(Exemplo: `BindingSource` classe).

[*Referencia*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Ways to Bind DataGridView in C# Windows Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-datagridview-in-window-forms-c-sharp/)
- [DataGridView.DataSource Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [DataGridView WinForms Control](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_populate_data_binding_genericlist.shtml)